# Getting the last day of month given a specific datetime variable in SAS EG

Tags: sql, sas

How do I get the last day of the month given a datetime variable like:

29DEC2022:00:00:00.000000

I want to convert the variable  to:
31DEC2023:00:00:00.000000

And get a similar result if I input the datetime variable:
15DEC2022:00:00:00.000000

I hope you can help me in the right direction

Comment: Your proposed value for the end of the month will miss most of the last day of the month.  Any time during that last day that is after the stroke of midnight is not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear if you want a date or datatime result.  This gives datetime.

```
37         data _null_;
38           x = '29DEC2022:00:00:00.000000'dt;
39           l = intnx('DTMONTH',x,0,'E');
40           put (x l)(=datetime.);
41         run;
    
x=29DEC22:00:00:00 l=31DEC22:23:59:59
```